# Manage or "export" widgets to the theme options page

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

I was wondering wether is was possible to some how "export" all the widget options or engine to the theme options page. So everything is in one place.

Got any idea?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have ever had to transfer a large number of widgets from one WordPress site to another, then you know that there’s really no easy way to get the exact same widget option settings added on another site. Manually adding all of your widgets on the other site can be quite tedious.
Widget Settings Importer/Exporter is a new plugin that aims to make this process much easier. It allows you to export your current widget settings and states as a json file and import them into another WordPress installation. If you already have widgets in place on the site where you’re importing settings, don’t worry because the plugin won’t overwrite any data currently within the sidebars.

This plugin has the potential to save you quite a bit of time. Download [Widget Settings Importer/Exporter](http://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-settings-importexport/) from the plugin repository.